# Axioms of Geometry?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, axioms, axiomatic-geometry

I have taken the generic low level undergraduate classes, such as Calculus 1-3, Differential Equations, and Linear algebra. Since I never learned Geometry past a basic high school level, I thought it would be cool for me to start from the axioms of Euclidean Geometry and try to prove/discover some geometry on my own. I did a little googling and found Euclid's $5$ postulates. However, other sources were talking about the existence additional axioms/postulates, such as the transitive property of equality, the partition axiom, etc. My question is, where is a good place for me to start? Should I just start with Euclid's $5$ postulates and assume the common rules I know from algebra (commutative property, etc.)? Are there more of these smaller axioms/postulates that are not generally talked about in "normal" math classes (calculus, etc.) that I should know about?

Comment: The first thorough book is Hilbert's *Foundations of Geometry*. Later, Tarski gave a first-order axiomatization. A book that you may find useful is the one by Hartshorne.

Comment: I think what you are referring to are usually called the [Common Notions](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/cn.html). There aren't too many of them, amazingly. But there are some things Euclid left out (or so it is claimed, I don't know) for a "modern" rigorous treatment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for the recommendation. However, for now I am interested in just the axioms and trying to "discover" some theorems myself, as I think it would help my mathematics maturity in general. When I reach my limit, of course I will learn geometry the right way from a book. But for now, is there a set of axioms (similar to Euclid's axioms, or possibly including them) which I can use to reach my goal? Am I prepared to get started being armed with just Euclid's 5 postulates and common notions from algebra (such as the transitive property of equality)?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Another way to put it, in addition to Euclid's axioms, are there additional postulates that I need to know about, such as "the ratio between the circumference of a circle and it's diameter is the same for all circles"?

Comment: Euclid is then enough from the axiomatic point of view. Or maybe one does not even need axioms. You might want to look at *Geometry Revisited* (Coxeter and Greitzer). From a research point of view, classical geometry is more or less dead. There may be more interesting things to explore.

Comment: John Lee (author of a very popular manifolds book) has a book on axiomatic geometry that looks good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I feel like I should have a strong basis in classical geometry before I do anything else, and additionally I think it's a good place to start since it is more intuitive and easier, specifically since I am trying to derive stuff from the axioms by myself. My concern is that I might be missing some information. I'm pretty sure I've asked a question here before about how the ancients knew that the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter is the same for all circles of any size, and if I remember correctly, the answer was basically "they just took it for granted" (continued)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am concerned about missing out on such facts which are not in Euclid's 5 axioms

Comment: If you do this, you will need a solid base of *theorems*. The *Elements* are not the best place to do this, modernized versions are quite a bit more accessible.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Are you saying that the gap between modern axioms and common theorems we learn in high school geometry is too large/difficult to cross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't take Euclid's axioms too seriously. It was the first known TRY to axiomatise geometry, but as it turned out Euclid in his proofs derived some properties from diagrams and tacitly assumed some facts.

The first theory which is purely based on deduction from axioms was given by David Hilbert in *Grundlagen der Geometrie* in 1899. You can deduce all theorems one would want to have in geometry without referring to diagrams at all as Hilbert said in his famous quote

> One must be able to say at all times--instead of points, straight lines, and planes--tables, chairs, and beer mugs

As for the matter of "common rules" (such as transitivity of equality). Hilbert's system is based on set theory so apart from geometry axioms we usually assume all ZFC axioms (and all logic rules). Besides, one would want to have the possibility to measure segments, angles, areas etc. (for instance measure of segments is needed in the formulation of Thales theorem) so we assume that we know the theory of real numbers. In fact, we may assume all results from all branches of mathematics.

I definetely recommend you to start with Hilbert axioms because they are the closest to Euclid's and the way I was taught to do synthetic geometry in secondary schools. You should also know that some of the axioms from the first original Hilbert's paper turned out to be redundant (because they were provable from other axioms) and also continuity axioms are now usually replaced with a different axiom.

Comment: Thank you, the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

It became clear a couple of hundred years ago that Euclid's axioms were flawed and incomplete. Even in his *first theorem* he implicitly assumes somthing that is not stated as an axiom (circles that "look like" they should intersect actually do have a point of intersection).

The two books I've heard are good are "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond" by Robin Hartshorne and "Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries" by Marvin Greenberg. They both cover the more modern approaches to plane geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. However, for now I am just trying to see if I can work my way from a set of axioms to some of those theorems I learned in high school geometry. Even if Euclid's axioms are not perfect, I don't think I will be noticing the inconsistency if it took people thousands of years to see them :P. Are Euclid's axioms and knowledge of general ideas from algebra (such as the commutative property) enough to just get me started?

Answer (score -1):

I think one can learn a ton by simply reading and working through $\textit{The Elements}$. Seeing how Euclid built upon everything, from the original definitions to the five axioms, is astonishing when you think about everything that can be shown. The algebraic principles you know can be derived and shown to be true geometrically through these definitions and axioms as well.